# How do I hande screen navigation perfectly with Flutter_bloc?

Tags: flutter, bloc

While using flutter_bloc, I am using blocbuilder to change screens according to current state. Now my question is how can I get back to my previous state to navigate previous screen using phones back button ?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your build method with Widget ** WillPopScope**

example:

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return new WillPopScope(
     onWillPop: _onWillPop,
     child: /// your widget,
   );
 }
```

And in ** _onWillPop** method you add the event of getting previous states and return false until the very first state is returned.

```
Future<bool> _onWillPop() async {
   if(BlocProvider.of<YourBloc>(context).state is! FirstState) {
      /// Add the event in YourBloc to fetch the previous states.
      ....
      ....
      return false;
   } else {
      return true;
   }
}
```